# Weird behavior of sed's backreference

Tags: sed, backreference

We have the following line of text:

```
| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
```

As you can see, the line of text simply consists of three similar phrases, which can be matched and changed (separately) using the following sed expression:

```
sed -n 's@| !\[.*\](\(\/img\/\)\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)) |@| ![\3](\1\2.\3.\4) |@p'
```

If we had just one phrase (instead of the given three), the result would be the following:

```
$ echo '| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) |' | sed -n 's@| !\[.*\](\(\/img\/\)\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)) |@| ![\3](\1\2.\3.\4) |@p'
| ![jakis-tam-text1](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) |
```

But when we have two or thee phrases, the result always points to the last matched phrase:

Here's an example with two matches:

```
$ echo '| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) |' | sed -n 's@| !\[.*\](\(\/img\/\)\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)) |@| ![\3](\1\2.\3.\4) |@p'
| ![jakis-tam-text2](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) |
```

And here's an example with three matches:

```
$  echo '| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |' | sed -n 's@| !\[.*\](\(\/img\/\)\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)) |@| ![\3](\1\2.\3.\4) |@p'
| ![jakis-tam-text3](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
```

Why does this happening?

Is there a way to force sed to print the result only for the very first match?

The expected behavior? I though the following command would print something similar to this (just the first match):

```
$  echo '| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |' | sed -n 's@| !\[.*\](\(\/img\/\)\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)) |@| ![\3](\1\2.\3.\4) |@p'
    | ![jakis-tam-text1](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) |
```

or this (all matches):

```
$  echo '| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |' | sed -n 's@| !\[.*\](\(\/img\/\)\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)) |@| ![\3](\1\2.\3.\4) |@p'
    | ![jakis-tam-text1](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![jakis-tam-text2](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![jakis-tam-text3](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not fully understand the question, but, you can try this `sed`

```
$ sed 's#\([^[]*.\)\([^\.]*.\([^\.]*\)[^)]*.\)#\1\3\2#' input_file
```

This will print all 3 matches but will only substitute into the first match

```
$ sed 's#\([^[]*.\)\([^\.]*.\([^\.]*\)[^)]*.\)#\1\3\2#' input_file
| ![jakis-tam-text1](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
```

To target all 3, the `g` flag can be added

```
sed 's#\([^[]*.\)\([^\.]*.\([^\.]*\)[^)]*.\)#\1\3\2#g' input_file
| ![jakis-tam-text1](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![jakis-tam-text2](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![jakis-tam-text3](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
```

You could also target just #2 for example

```
$ sed 's#\([^[]*.\)\([^\.]*.\([^\.]*\)[^)]*.\)#\1\3\2#2' input_file
| ![](/img/2016/12/020.jakis-tam-text1.png#medium) | ![jakis-tam-text2](/img/2016/12/021.jakis-tam-text2.png#medium) | ![](/img/2016/12/022.jakis-tam-text3.png#medium) |
```

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that `| !\[.*\]` matches the longest possible match. That is, the first phrase, up to the beginning of the last phrase. If you want to match only the first phrase you must be more specific. For instance with:

```
sed 's@| !\[\]\(([^.]*\.\([^.]*\)\.[^)]*)\) |.*@| ![\2]\1 |@'
```